# Android ActivityNotFoundException on custom data scheme

Tags: java, android

I have this link `<a href='/r/test'></a>` that represents a sub on reddit. I am trying to use a custom `intent-filter` to launch an activity that loads the sub (say, `reddit.com/r/test`) when the user clicks the link.

Here is what my manifest looks like right now:

```
    <activity android:name="reddit.RSubActivity">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="/r/.*" android:host="path"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

However, when I click on the link, that app crashes with:

```
09-02 17:26:29.425: E/AndroidRuntime(16972): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=/r/test (has extras) }
```

I've tried searching for the answer, and it looks like it is correct. Could somebody please tell me what is going on?

Comment: `/r/.*` is not a scheme. In a URL, the scheme is the left-most portion. In a Web URL, usually that would be `http` or `https`. `/r/.*` would be a `pathPattern`, though it would be simpler to use `/r/` as a `pathPrefix`.

Comment: So I should put http for the scheme even though there is no http inside the link? I tried doing that and putting the path prefix as /r/ but it doesn't work

Comment: "So I should put http for the scheme even though there is no http inside the link?" -- I do not know where this link is showing up. In Web development, your `href` is a relative URL, relative to whatever site is being loaded, and it will be converted into an absolute URL, including a scheme, when it is used.

Comment: Sorry I'm still not understanding... if you look at the link I posted, there is no actual url (just a reddit sub that starts with /r/). How do I have the intent filter recognize that? I did what you said before but it's not working.

Comment: "there is no actual url" -- it is [a relative URL](https://kb.iu.edu/d/abwp). Either it will be converted to an absolute URL, or it is useless. Since you still have not explained where this empty `<a href='/r/test'></a>` HTML is being used (in a Web browser? in a Chrome custom tab? in a `WebView`? in a `TextView` via `Html.fromHtml()`? something else?), nobody can really help you determine whether that relative URL will be converted into an absolute URL or whether it is useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full "test" subreddit URL would be: `https://www.reddit.com/r/test/`.

If you want to handle all subreddit URLs (not just the one for "test"), try this:

```
<activity android:name="reddit.RSubActivity">
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data
            android:scheme="https"
            android:host="www.reddit.com"
            android:pathPrefix="/r/"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

See [the documentation for the `<data>` element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html) for more information.